# C++ and Lua - Unprotected Error (bad callback)? How is this possible

Tags: c++, c, lua, ffi, luajit

I'm working with LuaJIT's FFI and I'm getting very strange results. This returns a `PANIC: Unprotected Error (bad callback)`:

```
function idle(ms)
    myDLL.myDLL_idle(session, ms)
end
```

But this simple print has fixed the problem.

```
function idle(ms)
    print("anything")
    myDLL.myDLL_idle(session, ms)
end
```

Another extremely odd solution is to use `myDLL.myDLL_idle()` inside the main function. How can this even be possible? It's not like I can just do any arbitrary function either if I put the call in a function, the only ones guaranteed to work are a print and sleep.

```
function idle(ms)
    myDLL.myDLL_idle(session, ms)
end

myDLL.myDLL_idle(session, ms) -- works
idle(ms) -- doesn't work (unless first line of idle() is a print statement)
```

It's doing the same thing but just in another function. And the print fixing it if I try putting it in a function method just add to the complete weirdness of this. This is a huge problem.

Comment: See [here](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_semantics.html#callback). The `print` function prevents your `idle` function from being JIT-compiled, so the problem never arises. Use `jit.off()` as mentioned in the link instead of `print` to avoid JIT-compilation of `idle`.

Comment: @siffiejoe Put that comment as an answer so it can be accepted. You guessed it exactly. Ty!

Comment: This was a nightmare to debug, I'll try to recommend a better error message to devs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_semantics.html#callback), LuaJIT doesn't allow an FFI-call to be JIT-compiled if the FFI-code calls a C function that calls back into Lua via a stored callback. In most cases LuaJIT will detect those calls and avoid compilation, but if it doesn't, it aborts with the "bad callback" error message. The extra `print` helped, because it prevented JIT-compilation (`print` is [not compiled atm](http://wiki.luajit.org/NYI#Base-Library).).

The proposed solution (instead of calling `print`) is to explicitly stop the FFI-call from being JIT-compiled using the `jit.off` function.